# "Someone wiped his dirty hands on my towel."

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

Recently, I came across the following sentence:

> Someone wiped his dirty hands on my towel.

My questions: why using "on"? Why not to use "with"?

Answer (score 2):

"With" could be correct.  It implies the use of a towel.  But "on" suggests that the dirt is now on the towel.  It implies that the person is complaining that their towel is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I am right in saying that you wipe a fixed object *with* something held in the hand (wipe the table with a cloth), but you wipe your hands or an implement *on* a surface (he wiped his hands on his trousers). You could use either when referring to a towel, but I suppose using *on* is seeing the towel as something fixed (perhaps it was hanging up).